# Which is the best way to resize custom marker icons depending on zoom level in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to resize some custom markers depending on zoom level in leaflet.
The 'zoomend' function only works with Circles.

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {   
        )            
        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
        myMarker.setRadius(currentZoom );
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change size of marker in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038153/change-size-of-marker-in-leaflet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map.on('zoomend', ...)` will still work for other types of marker, but only `circleMarker` has a `setRadius()` method.  For other markers, you need a different way of changing their size, such as [re-adding the marker's icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30983027/937094) with a new `iconSize` property.  Look at the Leaflet documentation for [Marker](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#marker) and [Icon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#icon) for more details.

Icons and CircleMarkers take a size in pixels, which normally remains the same when you zoom the map.  If you need them to keep a constant geographic size, you might need to use some of the [conversion methods](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-conversion-methods) to figure out the number of pixels between two lat/lng points; this varies with latitude as well as zoom level.

Comment: I did the re-adding stuff:

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
var myIcon= L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            iconUrl: 'icon.png',
            iconSize: [7.5, 7.5],
            iconAnchor: [0, 0]
        }
    });

var ic = new myIcon({iconSize: [7.5, 7.5]});
    var marker = L.marker([-15.7745457, -48.3575684], {icon: ic}).addTo(map);

map.on('zoomend', function() {
var actualZoom = map.getZoom();
var newSize = 60/((20 - actualZoom )*2);

var resizedIcon = new myIcon({iconSize: [newSize ,newSize ]});      
marker.setIcon(resizedIcon );
});
```